# Listener com.mycompany.test.util.RetryListener was not found in project's classpath

Tags: java, maven, testng

For some reason my pipeline is complaining about my retrylistener. This seems to run locally, but in the pipeline it doesn't seem to be working.

```xml
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="com.mycompany.test.util.RetryListener"/>
</listeners>
```

```java
package com.mycompany.test.util;

public class RetryListener implements IAnnotationTransformer {
//...
}
```

IAnnotationTransformer extends ITestNGListener

Error message:

```
[2023-05-03T19:33:03.596Z] Listener com.mycompany.test.util.RetryListener was not found in project's classpath
[2023-05-03T19:33:03.596Z] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
[2023-05-03T19:33:03.596Z] 
[2023-05-03T19:33:03.596Z] Listener com.mycompany.test.util.RetryListener was not found in project's classpath
[2023-05-03T19:33:03.596Z]  at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:656)
[2023-05-03T19:33:03.596Z]  at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:282)
[2023-05-03T19:33:03.596Z]  at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:245)
[2023-05-03T19:33:03.596Z]  at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1183)
[2023-05-03T19:33:03.596Z]  at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1011)
[2023-05-03T19:33:03.596Z]  at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:857)
[2023-05-03T19:33:03.596Z]  at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[2023-05-03T19:33:03.596Z]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
[2023-05-03T19:33:03.596Z]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
[2023-05-03T19:33:03.596Z]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
[2023-05-03T19:33:03.596Z]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[2023-05-03T19:33:03.596Z]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:202)
[2023-05-03T19:33:03.596Z]  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:198)
[2023-05-03T19:33:03.596Z]  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[2023-05-03T19:33:03.596Z]  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[2023-05-03T19:33:03.596Z]  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[2023-05-03T19:33:03.596Z]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[2023-05-03T19:33:03.596Z]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

[2023-05-03T19:33:03.596Z]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
.
.
.
[2023-05-03T19:33:03.597Z]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[2023-05-03T19:33:03.597Z]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[2023-05-03T19:33:03.597Z]     at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
[2023-05-03T19:33:03.597Z] Caused by: org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
```

Comment: Is it in the repository?

Comment: What do you mean? It's in the github repo and I run a build before running my tests in the pipeline

Comment: Please edit your question and add details. You can perhaps share a sample repo that will tell us what your repo looks like. Also when you run in CI, what is the maven command that you are using.